# regex (preg_match_all)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I can match this string `{string}` by using this regex : `/{(.*)}/s` in PHP's `preg_replace_callback` function.

But I don't what to match that string if that string is contained between tags like `{tag}{/tag}`,

For example :
I don't want to match `{string}` in `{tag} Anything Here {string} Anything Here {/tag}`.

Any suggestions (or maybe examples) are most welcome.

Comment: how many possible values for "tag" you have ? then it might be a simple task to do.

Comment: Is it possible that your tags might be nested?

Comment: @DhruvPathak : i think 3 possible values.

Comment: @MarkByers : yes it's possible

Comment: @Pawan: Then it's not a regular langauge, and regular expressions probably aren't the right tool.

Comment: Creating a parser will be much better than using regualr expressions in this case.

Comment: @MarkByers : which tool is right dude?

Comment: @JohnD : you got it, i'm creating a parser :)

Comment: @Pawan Uh, I hope you mean you realize this approach is wrong and you're properly creating a parser and not creating a "parser" using regular expressions.

Comment: @JohnD : i'm trying to create a parser by regular expressions, is there any other better way you know?

Comment: Doable but difficult. Since you are already using `preg_replace_callback` it would be easier to just match `{.*?}` any tags, and do the *within*-handling in the callback. Meaning your callback would implement the state machine and discern between tags you want to work on, and those that mark exceptions. -- Also your explanation of the tag structure is too superficial to get any helpful answers. Better search around for existing implementations on SO. Template parsing has been answered a couple of times (involves a `(?R)` recursing pattern, if you want to go the complex route..)

Comment: Creating a true parser involves stepping over each character and analyzing it's contents. The methods of doing this vary, so some research. Maybe some one else can help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with that :

```
preg_match_all("/(\{string\})|(\{tag\}.+\{.+tag\})/", $str, $m);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($m);
echo "</pre>";
```

As you will see, that expression will return a m with three array elements. The second array ellement contain all the {string} that are not into {tag}....{string}....{/tag}

Comment: How does that work with `preg_replace_callback`? Can you add another code example showing that function?

Comment: Because I have never use that function "preg_replace_callback" I can't  give you any good sugestion. But If you like you can describe what you like to get as result and I will search to find you the best solution.

Comment: I was just asking because in the OP it was asked for `preg_replace_callback`. I will edit the title so the question is not misleading.